# Replace character 'chain' with another character 'chain'

Tags: vba, excel

My little problem bellow :(

```
Option Compare Text

Sub pocetpismen()

With List1

Specialchar = "á.č.ř.ž.ý"
nonspec = "a.c.r.z.y"

    delka = Len(Cells(8, 6))

    delka1 = (delka - 1) / 2

leva = Left(Cells(8, 6), delka1)
prava = Right(Cells(8, 6), delka1)

                                            Cells(26, 4) = leva 'just to help me


For Each char In Split(Specialchar, ".")
    leva = Replace(leva, char, Split(nonspec, "."))
Next

                                            Cells(25, 4) = leva 'just to help me


     If leva = prava Then
         Cells(8, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)

       ElseIf leva <> prava Then
         Cells(8, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

     End If

End With
```

So in the part:

```
 For Each char In Split(Specialchar, ".")
        leva = Replace(leva, char, Split(nonspec, "."))
    Next
```

it doesn't replace the characters in order i want it to (it doesn't even run)

I don't want, for example, replace all characters defined in `Specialchar = "á.č.ř.ž.ý"` with single character like I would with

```
For Each char In Split(Specialchar, ".")
    leva = Replace(leva, char, "X")
Next
```

I want the `á` being always replaced to `a`, `č` to `c` and so on...
any help guys? **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Range.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx):

```
Sub RelaceThem()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:="á", Replacement:="a", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlPart
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:="č", Replacement:="c", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlPart
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:="ř", Replacement:="r", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlPart
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:="ž", Replacement:="z", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlPart
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:="ý", Replacement:="y", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlPart
End Sub
```

Do this same line of code for any other characters you want to replace.  Keep in mind this only works for lower case (I had it `MatchCase:=True`) but you could make 5 more lines for capital letter replacements.